# How to find a abulala in python file

Tags: python, file

"Tell us more about your question
Your description gives people the information they need to help you answer your question........."
If i want to find the index of "about "

i have tried using the re.search method and it cause error i don know why

```
    word="about"
    r = re.search(r'\b%s\b' % word, line)
    print(r.start()) #print index , but this one cause error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

my expected result is

```
"about" is found at index 15
```

but the result i got was

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Comment: Your code searches for the word on every line of the file.  If the word does not appear on the current line, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
print(r.start())
```

to

```
if r != None:
        print(r.start())
```